# Has_many through association form creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_many through association and I need to create a new record for `UserGroup` where the UserGroup is created within the Group controller.

In my `groups` controller I have this method

```
def add
  @usergroup = UserGroup.new
end
```

Here is my `UserGroup.rb` model

```
class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

In the `add.html.erb` view I have it render the form whos code is listed below.

```
<%= form_for(@usergroup) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id %>
  </div>

  <% form.text_field :group_id, value: @usergroup.id %>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However I am getting this error.

`undefined method`user_groups_path' for #<#:0x007fba7c11aab0>`

Can you not create a record this way? I want to have the url presented like this `http://localhost:3000/groups/4/add`.

Im somewhat new to Rails and forms for different models is where I get confused. Can anybody help me out with this?

#### Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :maps
  devise_for :users
  resources :groups do
    get 'add', on: :member
  end
  resources :rows

  root to: 'maps#index'
end
```

Comment: Could you show routes for this model?

Comment: Routes have been added.

Comment: Where're routes for `UserGroup`?

Comment: @MikhailKatrin No controller for UserGroups, only model.

Comment: Did you try to set method and path explicity `<%= form_for @usergroup, method: 'post', url: add_groups_path do |form| %>` ?

Comment: Ah yes, the problem is that the `add_groups_path` is actually `add_group_path`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159781/discussion-between-mikhail-katrin-and-trenton-tyler).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare an appropriate route. You going to `post` but set `get 'add'`.

```
post '/groups/:id/add'
resources :groups
```

Because of this you have get `add_group_path` instead of post `add_groups_path`

---

It'll be better to specify explicity method and url:

```
<%= form_for @usergroup, method: 'post', url: add_groups_path do |form| %>
```

And don't forget to permit params in controller

Comment: So what should my route look like if I already have this set? `resources :groups do
    get 'add', on: :member
  end`

Comment: answer updated, you have to set `post` insted of `get`

Comment: I am getting the this error when I try adding that route above :groups `No route matches [POST] "/groups/4/add"`